# When compiling Vue-cli project and serving with nginx, console prints " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' "

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nginx

I am trying to run my Vue-Cli project on my server with nginx. I am fairly certain my nginx is set up correctly but you can look it over.

This is on `vue 3.2.13`, `nginx 1.18.0` and `ubuntu 20.04.4`

```
root /var/www/html/;
index index.html;

location /vueProject/ {
         try_files $uri /vueProject/dist/index.html;
}
```

When visiting the page the console gives 2 errors

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` both linking to Javascript files `/js/chunk-vendors.44e4eb0a.js` & `/js/app.3856adea.js`.

From what I have read it seems to not be able to fetch those files. When I view them in the dev tools they aren't loaded, they just appear as the index.html file.

I have tried changing `publicPath:` in vue.config.js but that didn't change it and adding `.` in front of the path to the files didn't change it either. So I am thinking the files might not be loaded by nginx and if that is the issue how would I solve that?

Comment: `not be able to fetch those files` - you've set up nginx to server index.html if the actual uri is not found, which is why you are getting the error - let me guess, the js files are actually in `/vueProject/dist/js/` folder - so the problem is, that contents of `dist` probably should be in `/vueProject` ... e.g., index should be at `/vueProject/index.html` ... there should be a js folder in `/vueProject` and I believe you'd need to set the `publicPath` in `vue.config.js` as `/vueProject`

Comment: the TL;DR is - if you have `dist` in the path on the "production" site, you're likely deploying it wrong - the content of `dist` should be the root of the deployed "app"

Comment: I don't see how having the files in the dist folder can be a part of the problem. I am using the dist since it is the build folder for Vue so I don't need to move it every time. If I misunderstood you then please correct me.

Comment: what do you use to "serve" the http? Nginx? Apache? nodejs server? something else

Comment: It's served by nginx, nothing else. I have a react app hosted the exact same way which is working fine.

Comment: what's the deploy process you use? do you just just compile on the server directly where nginx is serving that "site"? If so, set nginx root to the `dist` folder

Comment: My deployment process is, downloading the code from github, running "npm i && npm run build" which will download dependencies and create the dist folder. 

I tried setting root to the dist folder and it made no impact. It returns the same errors.

Comment: I want to note that it runs completely fine when using the npm module "Serve"

Comment: yes, it would run fine like that because it probably uses dist as the root folder for the server - your nginx is not **configured correctly** to server using the dist folder as the root in that case

Comment: or, how about ... `try_files $uri /vueProject/dist/$uri /vueProject/dist/index.html;`

Comment: did you ever mention the path the browser is trying to use for the js files? that would help a lot in debugging the issue for you

Comment: I believe what you were saying about not having root in the correct folder was the reason. Though I haven't been able to get it how I want I know a different way I could do it using the prefix to the domain instead of /. I have run out of time so this will have to do. Thanks for trying :) Much love